How to propogate open telemetry span via kafka?
I want to propogate a trace from one service to another where I am sending data via Kafka.
I was able to create a child trace, using sort of below logic. But, opentelemetry agent doesn't send the child trace to otel-collector.
I am not understanding why this is not working. Is there a recommended way of serialising and passing context via propogators.
I was only able to find http propogator, so not sure how can I send data in byte array format.
Take an existing span and get its span context
spanContextParent := span.SpanContext()
parentTraceId := spanContextParent.TraceID()
parentSpanId := spanContextParent.SpanID()
Taking out the trace id and 
// taking original span context
stateByteArray := []byte(spanContext.TraceState().String())
traceByteArray := []byte(spanContext.TraceID().String())
spanByteArray := []byte(spanContext.SpanID().String())

// we send byte array via kafka producer
// Asssuming sending this string to some service now converting back
traceId, err := trace.TraceIDFromHex(string(traceByteArray))
if err != nil {
    return trace.SpanContextConfig{}, err
}

spanIDFromHex, err := trace.SpanIDFromHex(string(spanByteArray))
if err != nil {
    return trace.SpanContextConfig{}, err
}
traceState, err := trace.ParseTraceState(string(stateByteArray))
if err != nil {
    return trace.SpanContextConfig{}, err
}
config := trace.SpanContextConfig{
    TraceID:    traceId,
    SpanID:     spanIDFromHex,
    TraceState: traceState,
}
// start a child span
newSpanContext := trace.NewSpanContext(config.OtelParentSpanContextConfig)
remoteSpanContext := trace.ContextWithRemoteSpanContext(ctx, newSpanContext)
newCtx, dualSpan := m.StartSpan(remoteSpanContext, spanName)


You should use the propagator to inject and extract span context.
Propagators are not specific to HTTP, you just need to specify how to represent kafka headers.
opentelemetry-demo has examples of context propagation for sarama: producer and consumer

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
